# Java: cannot find symbol "file.asm".split(".")

Tags: java

My program:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.regex;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("file.asm".split("\\."));
    }
}
```

> Error:(4, 17) java: cannot find symbol   symbol:   class regex
>   location: package java.util

Comment: `import java.util.regex` -> `import java.util.regex.*` (although you could remove both `import`s in the code presented)

Comment: And you may want to escape the `.`.

Comment: Related question: How do I print the first element of the array that is returned. I tried: "file.asm".split("\\.").get(0). 

But that didn't work

Comment: @xingZì Try `System.out.println("file.asm".split("\\.")[0]);` split return an array, not a list

Comment: just means that the compiler cannot find "class regex" at "package java.util"

Answer (score 1):

The dot need escaping because is a special char for regex and you need tow slashs because slash itself has special meaning within Java strings.

- **`.`** is used for any mach in regex
- **`\`** is used as for escape sequence in java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString("file.asm".split("\\.")));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[file, asm]
```

Comment: No, I simply needed the ".*" at the end of "import java.util.regex"

Comment: There's no need to import regex at all, and you'll need to import `Arrays` instead  (in this solution)

Comment: @alfasin Correct, I've edited the post and added the complete code